# Javascript Date Issue Between Browsers

Tags: javascript, validation, google-chrome, date, blackberry-webworks

The format the function receives the two dates is:
YYYY/MM/DDTHH:MM

Year/month/dayThour:minutes

encase its unclear

```
function compareDates(start, end) {
    console.log("Start: " + start);
    console.log("END : " + end);

    var start1 = start.replace(/\T/g,' ')
    var start2 = new Date(start1);

    var end1 = end.replace(/\T/g,' ')
    var end2 = new Date(end1);

    console.log("Str 1: " + start1);
    console.log("Str 2: " + start2);    
    console.log("END 1: " + end1);
    console.log("END 2: " + end2);

    console.log((end - start));
    console.log((end - start) < 0);

    if ((end - start) < 0 || (end - start) == 0) {return false;}else{return true}
}
```

Orginal code before debugging

```
function compareDates(start, end) {
    start = new Date(start.replace(/\T/g,' '));
    end = new Date(end.replace(/\T/g,' '));
    if ((end - start) < 0 || (end - start) == 0) {return false;}else{return true}
}
```

The consoles are there for my error logging, in chrome this works fine with no errors and returns false if the end date is equal to or before my start date.

If I run in web-works, i get the following output problems
Str 2: Invalid Date
END 2: Invalid Date

What I don't understand is why this doesn't work in blackberry web-works but does in chrome and how do I solve this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your regex, have you tried removing the '\' before the 'T'?

You only need to use a leading-slash in that way if the character following it has special meaning to the regex engine (a capital T does not). It looks like Chrome is being lenient and ignoring the slash whereas the other browser is not.

Comment: How do i compare 2010/10/10 10:10 to 2010/10/10 10:09  ?

Comment: Found the issue are bashing my head of a wall contiously, your answer was correct + i had a typo ! thanks :)